# CSS 3 - Get transition on property : display

Tags: html, css, safari, transition

i got a little question when using the transition-effect with the property display:

I am testing on Safari:

```
input.input_field {
    display:none;
    transition-property: display;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-transition-property: display; /* Safari */
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s; /* Safari */
}
input.input_field_active {
    display:block;
}
```

But this example doesnt work for now, anybody knows why i cant use the the property : display??

Greetings!

Comment: The `display` property is not transitionalable.

Comment: so what a property could i use in this case?

Comment: its just about displaying the input-field with an effect..

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. If you need a fade-in effect look at `opacity`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property

Check this link hope you will get solution from this.

Answer (score 0):

**You can only perform a transition on a scalable property**, i.e. a numerically defined property (which may or may not have units of measurement) which exists within a range for which any two points are related. The reason for this is that in order to perform a transition the browser takes the starting point and ending point provided then extrapolates the interim keyframes- producing the resulting animation.

The display property is not scalable, it is simply 'on' or 'off', indeed more specifically it has a number of properties which arent related on any form of scale. As such, the interim values cannot be extrapolated. You can also look at it like this, `display` is also a layout and not visual style- although it does have visual connotations. You can only perform transitions on visual styles.

Depending on what your requirements are, you can perform a transition on `opacity` or `height` (or width).

### [Demo Fiddle of alternate transitions](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4ec8/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `visibility` in place of `display` and the use `opacity` as a fade effect.

`visibility` is transtionable although it also only has an on / off state BUT you can use a transition delay to affect it.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qLMWF/)

**HTML**

```
<button>Hover</button>

<div class="wrap">


</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    background-color: #bada55;
    margin-top: 25px;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0.5s,
                opacity 0.35s linear;
}

button:hover + .wrap {
  visibility:visible; /* show it on hover */
  opacity:1;
  transition-delay:0; 
}
```